# Getting Random Number for each row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with some names in a row. For each row I want to generate a random name. I wrote the following query to:

```
BEGIN transaction t1

Create table TestingName
(NameID int,
 FirstName varchar(100),
 LastName varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO TestingName
SELECT 0,'SpongeBob','SquarePants' 
UNION 
SELECT 1, 'Bugs', 'Bunny' 
UNION 
SELECT 2, 'Homer', 'Simpson' 
UNION 
SELECT 3, 'Mickey', 'Mouse' 
UNION 
SELECT 4, 'Fred', 'Flintstone'

SELECT FirstName from TestingName
WHERE NameID = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5

ROLLBACK Transaction t1
```

The problem is the "ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5" portion of this query sometime returns more than 1 row and sometimes returns 0 rows. I must be missing something but I can't see it.

If I change the query to

```
DECLARE @n int
set @n= ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5

SELECT FirstName from TestingName
WHERE NameID = @n
```

Then everything works and I get a random number per row.

If you take the query above and paste it into SQL management studio and run the first query a bunch of times you will see what I am attempting to describe.

The final update query will look like

```
Update TableWithABunchOfNames
set [FName] = (SELECT FirstName from TestingName
WHERE NameID = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5)
```

This does not work because sometimes I get more than 1 row and sometimes I get no rows.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are getting a different random value for each row.  That is the *problem*.  This query is probably doing a full table scan.  The `where` clause is executed for each row -- and a different random number is generated.

So, you might get a sequence of random numbers where none of the ids match.  Or a sequence where more than one matches.  On average, you'll have one match, but you don't want "on average", you want a guarantee.

This is when you want `rand()`, which produces only one random number per query:

```
SELECT FirstName
from TestingName
WHERE NameID = floor(rand() * 5);
```

This should get you one value.

Comment: I am trying to get different names for each row. If I use "rand()" then I get the same name for all the rows which is what I am trying to achieve with the ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5

Comment: @user299967 . . . Maybe you have a different question in mind, but this one seems clearly about returning one row from the `TestingName` table.  Returning more than one row is described as the problem, which seems to directly contradict your comment.  If you have a different question, please ask it as a separate question.  Editing your current question is likely to invalidate the answers, which draws downvotes.

Comment: You are right...I guess I should have been more clear the first time, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use top 1?

```
Select top 1 firstName
From testingName
Order by newId()
```

Comment: Because sometimes we get 0 rows :-(

Comment: This should always produce one row.  The reason you don't want to use it primarily because it is expensive (particularly if there are more names).

Comment: This will generate the same value in case of nested subquery (e.g. `SELECT val1, (YOUR_QUERY) FROM tbl`)

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow yes, but only if the subquery is not correlated with the main query, and anyway that's not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,FName
        ,CAST(5 * (CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as int) / 4294967295.0 + 0.5) AS int) AS rr
    FROM
        dbo.TableWithABunchOfNames
)
,CTE_ForUpdate
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE.ID
        , CTE.FName
        , dbo.TestingName.FirstName AS RandomName
    FROM
        CTE
        LEFT JOIN dbo.TestingName ON dbo.TestingName.NameID = CTE.rr
)
UPDATE CTE_ForUpdate
SET FName = RandomName
;
```

**This solution depends on how smart optimizer is.**

For example, if I use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` (which is the correct choice for this query), optimizer would move calculation of random numbers outside the join loop and end result would be not what we expect.

I created a table `TestingName` with 5 rows as in the question and a table `TableWithABunchOfNames` with 100 rows.

Here is the execution plan with `LEFT JOIN`. You can see the `Compute scalar` that calculates random numbers is done before the join loop. You can see that 100 rows were updated:

[image: left join]

Here is the execution plan with `INNER JOIN`. You can see the `Compute scalar` that calculates random numbers is done after the join loop and with extra filter. This query may update not all rows in `TableWithABunchOfNames` and some rows in `TableWithABunchOfNames` may be updated several times. You can see that `Filter` left 102 rows and `Stream aggregate` left only 69 rows. It means that only 69 rows were eventually updated and also there were multiple matches for some rows (102 - 69 = 33).

[image: inner join]

---

To guarantee that the result is what you expect you should generate random number for each row in `TableWithABunchOfNames` and explicitly remember the result, i.e. materialize the `CTE` shown above. Then use this temporary result to join with the table `TestingName`.

You can add a column to `TableWithABunchOfNames` to store generated random numbers or save `CTE` to a temp table or table variable.